# Java Swing can run in JDK 1.8 or it needs latest version

Tags: java

Is Java Swing need JDK 1.8 version or it can run in any JDK Versions.Because JDK latest Version didn't support applets and AWT programs

Answer (score 6):

Swing runs in everything from java 1.1 (30 years old at this point) to JDK18 (released 2 days ago). AWT is still supported (Swing is built on top of it, even, certain parts anyway). Whomever told you that 'AWT programs are not supported' is misinformed.

Applets are no longer supported - that's true. Haven't been for decades.

Answer (score 2):

See white paper by Oracle: [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf), 2020-05.

## Applets

Oracle and the Java community have been phasing out [Java Applet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) support from [Java SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition).

All web browser makers have halted support for Java Applets.

The modern options to deploy Java GUI apps include:

- Bundle your app with a JVM to be installed on the desktop computer. See Java JEPs [282](https://openjdk.org/jeps/282) and [392](https://openjdk.org/jeps/392).
- Use [*OpenWebStart*](https://openwebstart.com) to deliver the app to a desktop computer on which a Java runtime is installed. May be practical in a controlled environment such as a corporation or an educational institution.
- Write your app in Java using the [*Vaadin Flow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow_(Java_API)) framework, running on a server, with user-interface rendered using Web technologies to auto-generate HTML/CSS/JavaScript for display remotely in the user’s web browser.

## Swing

[Answer by rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71629763/642706) is correct.

[Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) is a required part of Java, always included, still supported, but no longer under active development (in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode)).

## JavaFX

Swing’s official replacement, [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX), is under active development as [*OpenJFX*](https://openjfx.io/). The project is co-led by [Gluon](https://gluonhq.com/) and [Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation). New releases arrive around the same time as releases of Java, one every six months.

OpenJFX libraries are available to add to your project. Alternatively, at least two vendors bundle the OpenJFX libraries with an edition of their [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) offering: *ZuluFX* by Azul Systems, and *LibericaFX* by BellSoft.